# Making a save button work in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to build a GUI that will allow users to enter basic details about themselves for a new patient form and have that information saved to a .txt file. This data should then be viewable at a later time, but I can't get the save button to work.

```
    //Import packages

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
```

//Main class

public class PatientDetailsWindow{

```
//Declare variables
public JFrame frame1;
public JPanel panel;
public JButton btnSave, btnExit;
public JLabel lblFirstName, lblSurname, lblGender, lblDOB, lblSmoker, lblMedHistory, lblFSlash1, lblFSlash2, lblImage;
public JTextField txtFirstName, txtSurname, txtGender,  txtSmoker, txtMedHistory, txtDOB1, txtDOB2, txtDOB3;
public Insets insets;
public JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();



public static void main (String args[]){
    new PatientDetailsWindow();  
}

public PatientDetailsWindow(){
    createFrame();
    createLabels();
    createTextFields();
    createButtons();

}

//Create the frame
public void createFrame(){
    frame1 = new JFrame ("Personal details");
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setSize (600,600);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    frame1.add(panel);
    frame1.setVisible(true);

}

//Creating Labels
public void createLabels(){
    lblFirstName = new JLabel ("First Name: ");
    lblFirstName.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 20);
    lblFirstName.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (lblFirstName);

    lblSurname = new JLabel ("Surname: ");
    lblSurname.setBounds(50, 100, 500, 20);
    lblSurname.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (lblSurname);

    lblGender = new JLabel ("Gender: ");
    lblGender.setBounds(50, 150, 500, 20);
    lblGender.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (lblGender);


    lblDOB = new JLabel ("Date of Birth: "); 
    lblDOB.setBounds(50, 200, 500, 20);
    lblDOB.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (lblDOB);

    lblFSlash1 = new JLabel ("/"); 
    lblFSlash1.setBounds(440, 200, 20, 20);
    lblFSlash1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (lblFSlash1);

    lblFSlash2 = new JLabel ("/"); 
    lblFSlash2.setBounds(490, 200, 40, 20);
    lblFSlash2.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (lblFSlash2);

    lblSmoker = new JLabel ("Are you a smoker? ");
    lblSmoker.setBounds(50, 250, 500, 20);
    lblSmoker.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (lblSmoker);

    lblMedHistory = new JLabel ("Any other previous medical history? ");
    lblMedHistory.setBounds(50, 300, 500, 20);
    lblMedHistory.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (lblMedHistory);


    /*ImageIcon image= new ImageIcon("heartandstethoscope.jpg");
    JLabel lblImage = new JLabel(image);
    panel.add(lblImage);
     */
}

//Creating Text Fields
public void createTextFields(){
    txtFirstName = new JTextField (10);
    txtFirstName.setBounds(400, 50, 100, 20);
    txtFirstName.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (txtFirstName);

    txtSurname = new JTextField  (10);
    txtSurname.setBounds(400, 100, 100, 20);
    txtSurname.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (txtSurname);

    txtGender = new JTextField  (10);
    txtGender.setBounds(400, 150, 100, 20);
    txtGender.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (txtGender);

    txtDOB1 = new JTextField  (2);
    txtDOB1.setBounds(400, 200, 40, 20);
    txtDOB1.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (txtDOB1);

    txtDOB2 = new JTextField  (2);
    txtDOB2.setBounds(450, 200, 40, 20);
    txtDOB2.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (txtDOB2);

    txtDOB3 = new JTextField  (4);
    txtDOB3.setBounds(500, 200, 80, 20);
    txtDOB3.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (txtDOB3);

    txtSmoker = new JTextField (3);
    txtSmoker.setBounds(400, 250, 100, 20);
    txtSmoker.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (txtSmoker);

    txtMedHistory = new JTextField (300);
    txtMedHistory.setBounds(400, 300, 100, 60);
    txtMedHistory.setForeground(Color.blue);
    panel.add (txtMedHistory);

    JScrollPane areaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtMedHistory);
    areaScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    textArea.setBounds(400, 300, 100, 80);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);


    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setEditable(true);
    textArea.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(textArea);
}

//Creating buttons
public void createButtons(){
    btnSave = new JButton ("Save");
    btnSave.setBounds(130, 350, 100, 20);
    btnSave.setForeground(Color.blue);
    btnSave.addActionListener(new SaveHandler());
    panel.add (btnSave);
    btnSave.setVisible(true);

    btnExit = new JButton ("Exit");
    btnExit.setBounds(240, 350, 100, 20);
    btnExit.setForeground(Color.blue);
    btnExit.addActionListener(new ExitHandler());
    panel.add (btnExit);
    btnExit.setVisible(true);
}

class ExitHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame1, 
                "Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("EXIT SUCCESSFUL");
        }
    }
}

class SaveHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try(  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( "DetailsofPatient.txt" )){
            out.println(txtFirstName.getText());
            out.println(txtGender.getText());
            out.println(txtDOB1.getText());
            out.println(txtDOB2.getText());
            out.println(txtDOB3.getText());
            out.println(txtSmoker.getText());
            out.println(txtMedHistory.getText());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Save successful");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what doesn't work about the save button ? the file doesn't change for example ? or exception is thrown ?

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what happens? Is there an error, or does nothing happen, or does something unexpected happen?

Comment: It just wont save anything to the file, there's no error message but it wont save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright for starters, you didn't add an ActionListener to your save button, so you need to add it like this.

```
 btnSave = new JButton ("Save");
    btnSave.setBounds(130, 350, 100, 20);
    btnSave.setForeground(Color.blue);
    btnSave.addActionListener(new SaveHandler());
    panel.add (btnSave);
    btnSave.setVisible(true);
```

Also, in your `SaveHandler`, your `PrintWriter` isn't actually printing anything.

Your Code: `out.println(  );` would not write anything.

Let's say you wanted to write the contents of txtFirstName, you would need to do

`out.println(txtFirstName.getText());`

Edit: You also need another closing braces at the end of your ExitHandler class

```
class ExitHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame1, 
                "Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("EXIT SUCCESSFUL");
        }
    }
}
```

You will also then need to remove a closing brace at the end of the program.

Comment: i was just about to post.

Comment: I did try that, however the SaveHandler has the error message "Cannot be resolved to a type":


//Creating buttons
 public void createButtons(){
  btnSave = new JButton ("Save");
     btnSave.setBounds(130, 350, 100, 20);
     btnSave.setForeground(Color.blue);
     btnSave.addActionListener(new SaveHandler());
     panel.add (btnSave);
     btnSave.setVisible(true);


Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Austin Thank you so much! But I'm not seeing the entered information actually save to the .txt file?

Comment: Do you think the error could be in the following section? ` class SaveHandler implements ActionListener{

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    try(  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( "DetailsofPatient.txt" )){
     out.println(  );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Save");
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: @OlleHawes You still aren't having your PrintWriter actually write anything. Re-read my post from this point on: `Let's say you wanted to write the contents of txtFirstName, you would need to do`

Comment: @Austin Thanks again, I have done this, but still not working properly?

Comment: @OlleHawes can you show me all of your code again please? You can either upload to pastebin or update your main question.

Comment: @OlleHawes Are you checking in all of the directories in your project? It's creating the file for me and writing correctly. You aren't receiving any errors when you click it are you?

Comment: @Austin I've just checked, I had the .txt file in the directories in Eclipse, When checking using finder (I'm on Mac) I've found the correct file. Thank you so much for your help Austin. You are a hero!

Comment: @OlleHawes No problem Olle, set my answer to correct if your question is answered then :) Stick with it!

Comment: @Austin Have done. I'll try! I'm really out of my depth here hahah!